# can't run three js loader in browser

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to download the codes and test it on my localhost, this codes were from Three js example official on sandbox, but when I implement on my browser nothing show the off the model

this is the link https://codesandbox.io/s/y2qwy6r2kz

how correctly run that three js ? because it is blank on my browser when I run it with live-server or http-server live

Comment: Have you included the dependency i.e. the three.js package?

Comment: Also, Always check the output in the browser console, it should give you a clue as to what is wrong.

Comment: @M.T yes I did on .js file to import them, but it doesnt work,

Comment: @2pha it said nothing on browser console really, that is why I get confused why it happend

Comment: You have not given us enough information to help you further